# How is the blockchain used with the Brave browser?

Tags: blockchain

I am not sure if here is the correct place to ask this question. I just want to know if there is someone who is familiar with this topic and if they do, they can answer the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866230/how-is-the-blockchain-used-with-the-brave-browser).

There does not seem to be any detailed information regarding this point when it comes to Brave browsers on the Internet. Even [this quora question](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Do-you-understand-how-the-blockchain-and-digital-currency-are-used-with-the-Brave-browser) does not have any answers despite the number of followers.

I would appreciate any answers regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Payments tab under Brave's preferences helps to clarify the blockchain aspect quite a bit. Basically: Brave Payments is an attempt to replace the necessity of running advertisements for publications you visit to pay their bills and feed their staff. The BAT token, which is traded on markets and holds value, is used to make micropayments to publishers who's work you're viewing online. These numbers aren't accurate at all, but, for example: You load 50 BAT into your browser's wallet. If you spend 4 minutes reading an article from TheFutureOfNews.eth, you will transfer 0.1 BAT to that publisher. This way, incentive is created for work to be created and viewed, without the need for obtrusive advertising in between the viewer and creator.

As the BAT token and Brave browser are a web3 project, the proper place for the question would be over at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "for a vacuum cleaner to be involved"?

Comment: I meant "an ad unrelated to the material," I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "Payments tab under Brave's preferences"? Is it a website or something in the Brave's browser? I just checked the browser on my tablet, and can not find this tab. Also why is blockchain essential for the implementation of the function you described?

Comment: The mobile version will be adopting Brave Payments in a future release, the desktop browser looks like this. As an asset with a fixed amount on the Ethereum chain, the BAT token is able to 1) find, and eventually stabilize at, a value derived by the market, 2) utilize an immutable, decentralized ledger that removes the necessity for a third, governing party, and 3) allow information to be anonymously shard between publishers, advertises, and audiences that benefit all three.

Comment: I can't edit, but: The desktop payments look like

![this](https://i.imgur.com/NRerexy.png).

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct that the blockchain in the context of Brave browser is just to share information which would benefit the three parties? (Or does it also include payment of BAT token?)